# Selenium is unable to find a specific button to click

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium on Python to automate my checkout process on a website. The problem is I am unable to click the "Continue To Order Review" button and have tried multiple approaches. The error I keep receiving is **"Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"**.

I tried to use explicit wait and it did not work:

`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@data-attr='continueToOrderReviewBtn']"))).click()`

---

I also tried to find the button with text that it contains:

```
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Continue To Order Review')]")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Button not found")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```

---

The buttons div tag is as follows:
[image]

```
<div class="ncss-col-sm-12 pb5-sm prl5-sm va-sm-t ta-sm-r">
   <button data-attr="continueToOrderReviewBtn" class="ncss-brand pt2-sm pr5-sm pb2-sm pl5-sm ncss-btn-accent continueOrderReviewBtn mod-button-width ncss-brand
                    pt3-sm prl5-sm pb3-sm pt2-lg pb2-lg d-sm-b d-md-ib u-uppercase u-rounded fs14-sm">Continue To Order Review</button>
</div>
```

---

The html is not wrapped in an iFrame. I also tried to search for the buttons respective xpath but the script still can't seem to find and click it. I am still new to using Selenium and learning something new about it everyday but it seems that I can't get around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Due to DOM operation, some element may be temporary inaccessible or it is loaded more than one time. It cause the stale element reference which you receive.

Solution for this problem is to load element more than one time:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Continue To Order Review')]")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Button not found")
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight and answer. Unfortunately, the script still can't find the button and click it.

Answer (score 0):

### three ways to click on an element in selenium webdriver

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.get('https://www.examplesitenike.com')
# dret = ngRet({},ddriver,doptions) 

element=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="gen-nav-commerce-header-v2"]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/button')


modalwindow=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="pre-modal-view"]')


if not modalwindow.is_displayed():
    try:element.click()
    except:pass

if not modalwindow.is_displayed():
    try:driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    except:pass

if not modalwindow.is_displayed():
    element.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)

inputemail=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="email"]')
if inputemail.is_displayed():
    inputemail.send_keys('mylogin')
    

inputemail=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="password"]')
if inputemail.is_displayed():
    inputemail.send_keys('mypassword')
```

Comment: Hi. I get this error when I ran it: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(text(),'Continue To Order Review')]"}

Comment: Can you give me the url for me to create a solution? I'm interested in atypical cases)

Comment: Introduced three ways to click on an element . Is work!
However, another option is possible - to avoid pressing the button. To do this, you can register data at https://www.nike.com/login